# Onclick Listeners to Dynamically Loaded HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, onclick, onclicklistener

I'm trying to dynamically load a menu with JavaScript, then set onclick event listeners to the elements of the menu, after they are loaded.  I can't seem to figure out how to do that.  I am loading the menu through an AJAX call, the menu contents load fine, but nothing is happening when I click on the menu elements like I would expect.

This is the section of my code which I expect to be the cause...

```
//Load Menu and main images
window.onload = function()
{
    load_menu();   
}

document.getElementById('menu').onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('projects-button').onclick = load_projects_view();
}

//Load menu function
function load_menu()
{   
    request = getHTTPObject();
    request.onreadystatechange = append_menu;
    request.open("GET", "./php/menu.php", true);
    request.send(null);
}

//Load Project View
function load_projects_view()
{
    request = getHTTPObject();
    request.onreadystatechange = append_project_view;
    request.open("GET", "./php/project_view.php", true);
    request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: This is a prime example of why libraries like jQuery were created.

Comment: I understand there is jQuery, but I would like to learn how the language works without jQuery before I start to implement that...

Comment: Is the projects-button within the menu? Is `document.getElementById('projects-button').onclick = load_projects_view();` what you are expecting to fire?

Comment: Yes. `projects-button` is within the dynamically loaded HTML (Menu).  I wishing to execute another AJAX call - `load_projects_view()` when `projects-button` is clicked...

Comment: @nathansizemore I fully support your reluctance to use jQuery. Even once you're satisfied with your learning endeavor, jQuery is an unnecessary, bulky crutch 99% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this.

```
document.getElementById('menu').onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('projects-button').onclick = load_projects_view();
}
```

And put this at the bottom of `append_menu()`.

```
    document.getElementById('projects-button').onclick = load_projects_view;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well is the element with the id menu already available  when the javascript line:

```
document.getElementById('menu').onload = ...
```

is executed.
This line is executed before the

```
window.onload
```

occurs.

Well I would, probably call the code:

```
document.getElementById('projects-button').onclick = load_projects_view();
```

At the moment the menu items are added (your append_menu function?)

But it's hard to say because it is just a snip of code.

Also jQuery and dojo are definitly the way to go, also I think jQuery is a very good starting point to get the basics of the language because it hides all the strange browser behavior.

Comment: No, it is not.  Is there a way to execute a function once an element appears?
Chrome Stable